# PREFIX uitextfiled with a value that cannot be deleted

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, nsnotificationcenter, uitextfielddelegate

I have the following code which it doesn t seem to work

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
        if ((textField.text.length == defaultPrefix.length) && [string isEqualToString:@""]) {//When detect backspace when have one character.
            textField.text=defaultPrefix;
        }
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

        if (textField.text.length == 0) {
            textField.text = defaultPrefix;
        }
    return YES;
}
```

`defaultPrefix` is an NSString* value which is taken from a `UIPickerView`. When I am trying to delete the `defaultPrefix` value, the `textField` is not filled with the `prefixValue`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I hope my answer can help you

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the better approach to your problem is to use `NSNotificationCenter` with `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification`

Then you can add this code to `viewDidLoad`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(defaultPrefix:) name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:self.textField];
self.textField.text = self.defaultPrefix;
```

then, you only need to add the selector method, e.g.:

```
- (void) defaultPrefix: (NSNotification*) notification
{
    UITextField *notificationTextField = [notification object];    
    if (notificationTextField == self.textField)
    {
        if ([self.textField.text length] <= [self.defaultPrefix length])
        {
            self.textField.text = self.defaultPrefix;
        }
    }
}
```

You can check an example [here](https://github.com/GabrielMassana/defaultPrefix).